# ASP.NET Core MVC apply isotope filter on product page details

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-isotope

I applied isotope filter on my .Net core project dynamically. I successfully did it but a single minor error occur. After selecting the particular category position of the product not came first. Below see my two images

[All Product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XucA.jpg)

[After Filter check the position of that image not changed(its need to come first)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhPs6.png)

My code Below
Index.cshtml

```
@model BornoMala.Models.ViewModels.ProductDetailsVM
<section id="portfolio" class="portfolio">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" data-aos="fade-up">
            <div class="col-lg-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <ul id="portfolio-flters">
                    <li data-filter="all" class="filter-active filter-button">All</li>
                    @foreach (var obj in Model.Categories)
                    {
                        <li class="filter-button" data-filter="@obj.Name.Replace(' ','_')">@obj.Name</li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row portfolio-container" data-aos="fade-up">
            @foreach (var prod in Model.Products)
            {
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item  filter @Model.Category.Name.Replace(' 
                 ','_')">
                   <div class="portfolio-img"><img src="@Model.ImageUrl" class="img-fluid" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="portfolio-info">
                    <h4>@Model.Title</h4>
                    <p>By <b>@Model.Title</b></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            }
        </div>

    </div>
</section>
```

Isotope.js

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
        var portfolioIsotope = $('.portfolio-container').isotope({
            itemSelector: '.portfolio-item',
        });
});

 $(document).ready(function () {

            $(".filter-button").click(function () {
                $("#portfolio-flters li").removeClass('filter-active');
                $(this).addClass('filter-active');

                var value = $(this).attr('data-filter');
                if (value == "all") {
                    $('.portfolio-item').show('3000');
                }
                else {
                    $(".portfolio-item").not('.' + value).hide('2000');
                    $('.portfolio-item').filter('.' + value).show('2000');

                }
            });

    });
```

If i remove ..portfolio-container class  **on load window from isotope.js** then details page container not flexible check my another image(But the filter working properly)..

[Image card not flexible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNX6F.jpg)

Comment: anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways:

**1,Only change window onload part to:**

```
$('.portfolio-container').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.element-item'
    });
```

Then it will be showed to the first one, but it will take some time to move **in my demo**.
[image]

**2,Try another way to use isotope:**

Mind the **data-filter** content in  **'portfolio-flters'**, it may different from your's. This way's

principle is to **call isotope everytime** when you click the different filter button

(different data-filter).

**Edited code:**

Mind `data-filter=".@obj.Name.Replace(' ','_')">@obj.Name</li>` Data stored in database

is Digital,but you can **add '.' before '@'**,so it can be recognized by isotope.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row" data-aos="fade-up">
    <div class="col-lg-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <ul id="portfolio-flters">
            <li data-filter="*" class="filter-active filter-button">All</li>
            @foreach (var obj in Model.Categories)
            {
                <li class="filter-button" data-filter=".@obj.Name.Replace(' ','_')">@obj.Name</li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row portfolio-container" data-aos="fade-up">
    @foreach (var product in Model.Products)
    {
        <partial name="_IndividualProductCard" model="product" />
    }
</div>
```

```
@section Scripts
{
<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $mygrid = $('.portfolio-container').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.portfolio-item'
    });

    $('#portfolio-flters').on('click', 'li', function () {
        var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $mygrid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
    });
</script>
}
```

Data in database:

[image]
[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: in second method you use static item...when I first try I use same JS method its work but dynamically(get all products and categorys from DB) its not working..

Comment: You put data-filter=".Digital" on Category and apply that filter on image class ` <div class=" col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item  filter Drawing">` but in dynamically how its possible

Comment: @SoumikMahajan just need to add '.' before '@obj.Name.Repl...'

Comment: check below "Add answer" area i follow your code then this happened @tisa

Comment: @SoumikMahajan I offered whole code , include data in database,  you can try it. About your script, I don't understand 'show 0010' means. To call the $mygrid, you should get the data-filter value and then `$mygrid.isotope({ filter: $(this).attr('data-filter') });`

Comment: it solved thank you.. i add "." before @obj.name...you mention this before I tried and solved

Comment: @SoumikMahajan That's good, could you please [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? So it will be easier for others to find the answer.

Comment: @SoumikMahajan low reputation can't vote, but you can mark, that green ✓

Comment: yeah I got it.. can you tell me one more thing .. suppose in product db I have total 20 product .. but Isotope product details i want to show 10 times...how is this possible?

Comment: I want to specific item like only show top 10  product on my list using isotope not show all product(like a website home page i want to show only 10 item not all product)

Comment: @SoumikMahajan You can try something like [paging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-5.0) This is a new question, If you have problem, you should better post a new thread.

Comment: Hey @Tisa I have another question I filter the category and I also want to  sorting the Subcategory in same product page..

Answer (score 0):

@Tisa
I follow your code like this as you said
Index.cshtml

```
<section  class="portfolio">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" data-aos="fade-up">
            <div class="col-lg-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <ul id="portfolio-flters">
                    <li data-filter="*" class="filter-active filter-button">All</li>
                    @foreach (var obj in Model.Categories)
                    {
                        <li class="filter-button" data-filter="@obj.Name.Replace(' 
                        ','_')">@obj.Name</li>

                    }

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row portfolio-container" data-aos="fade-up">
            @foreach (var product in Model.Products)
            {
                <partial name="_IndividualProductCard" model="product" />
            }

        </div>

    </div>
</section>
```

_IndividualProductCard.cshtml

```
@model BornoMala.Models.Product
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item  filter @Model.Category.Name.Replace(' ','_')">
    <div class="portfolio-img ">
        <img src="@Model.ImageUrl" width="100" height="50" />
    </div>
</div>
```

```
 @section Scripts
    {
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $mygrid = $('.portfolio-container').isotope({
                itemSelector: '.portfolio-item'
            });

            $('#portfolio-flters').on('click', 'li', function () {
                var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
                $mygrid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
            });
        </script>
    }
```

product model

```
namespace project.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Artist { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Range(1,1000)]
        public double Price { get; set; }

        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
        public Category Category { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int StyleId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("StyleId")]
        public Style Style { get; set; }
    }
}
```

productdetailsVM

```
namespace project.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class ProductDetailsVM
    {
        public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        
    }
}
```

But All category image show others no image showing
[blank image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZw4h.png)

**I fix the filtering already with jquery but the problem is the pic position not change because of "$mygrid" not calling so how to call that**

```
@section Scripts{

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
   <script>
            $mygrid = $('.portfolio-container').isotope({
                itemSelector: '.portfolio-item'
            });

            $(".filter-button").click(function(){

                var value = $(this).attr('data-filter');
                if(value == "all")
                 {
                   $('.filter').show('0010');
                 }
            else
                  {
                    $(".filter").not('.'+value).hide('0010');
                    $('.filter').filter('.'+value).show('0010');

               }
            });
   </script>
```

Comment: @Tisa now check